# Keyof inferring string | number when key is only a string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I define an `AbstractModel` like so:

```
export interface AbstractModel {
   [key: string]: any
}
```

Then I declare the type `Keys`:

```
export type Keys = keyof AbstractModel;
```

I would expect that anything with the Keys type would be interpreted univocally as a string, for example:

```
const test: Keys;
test.toLowercase(); // Error: Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'string | number'. Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

Is this a bug of Typescript (2.9.2), or am I missing something?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

As defined in the Release Notes of TypeScript 2.9, if you keyof an interface with a string index signature it returns a union of string and number

> Given an object type X, keyof X is resolved as follows:
>
> If X contains a string index signature, keyof X is a union of string, number, and the literal types representing symbol-like properties, otherwise
>
> If X contains a numeric index signature, keyof X is a union of number and the literal types representing string-like and symbol-like properties, otherwise
>
> keyof X is a union of the literal types representing string-like, number-like, and symbol-like properties.

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html)

This is because: JavaScript converts numbers to strings when indexing an object:

> [..] when indexing with a number, JavaScript will actually convert that to a string before indexing into an object. That means that indexing with 100 (a number) is the same thing as indexing with "100" (a string), so the two need to be consistent.

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

Example:

```
let abc: AbstractModel = {
    1: "one",
};

console.log(abc[1] === abc["1"]); // true
```

When you only want the string keys, then you could only extract the string keys from your interface like so:

```
type StringKeys = Extract<keyof AbstractModel, string>;

const test: StringKeys;
test.toLowerCase(); // no error
```

Also the TypeScript compiler provides an option to get the pre 2.9 behavior of `keyof`:

> keyofStringsOnly (boolean) default `false`
>
> Resolve `keyof` to string valued property names only (no numbers or symbols).

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: `Extract<keyof Record<string, any>, "string">` always return `never` instead of `string`... why ?

Comment: @Aure77 Try to remove the double quotes around `string`

Answer (score 97):

I have faced similar problem. I resolved it by enforcing key to be string:

```
export type Keys = keyof AbstractModel & string;
```

Other option would be to convert key to string: `test.toString().toLowercase()`

Comment: Very useful, great contextual alternative to setting the `keyofStringsOnly: true` option globally.

Comment: Hmm... so why doesn't this work with `type PickNumericProperties<T> = Pick<T, keyof {[k: keyof T]: number}>` ?

Comment: Are there any practical differences between this and `Extract<keyof AbstractModel, string>`??

Answer (score 23):

For a generic typescript utility, you can use the following:

```
type KeyOf<T extends object> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
```

Usage:

```
const sym = Symbol();

const obj = {
  [sym]: true,
  foo: 'foobar',
  bar: 'barfoo',
  1: 'lorem'
}

let key: KeyOf<typeof obj> = 'foo'; // 'foo' | 'bar'

key = 'bar'; // ok
key = 'fool'; // error
key = 1; // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmAeAKlCAPYEB2AJgM5QD2ARgFYQDGwAfFALxQCiOATgIZ0oDW8UkihoANFCLAOASzwBzegG4AUMpqk8kiSAC2zKAGVd5UgBsAFAEoVajVoqV9Ab2VQoAbSK6AugC4oUgCuEKKuUEikpP4A5BEUXBzRoW7kCTGpHHFJYQCMMaakHBA60coAvqqmEMBQAiD+cIiooJBCZFSMLLGR0YpQAPT9UN2k0VAAPsMZpcp1+tHTfYNkfLPw83GmvQNDEBwchWsg+jlLu-uFQA)

Comment: You could also call it `StringKeyOf` to explain to other developers / yourself in 6 months why you used `KeyOf<...>` rather than just `keyof ...`

Comment: @Ethan well, we tend to always have strings as keys of an object, as we don't use `Symbol`. But I guess it doesn't hurt to be more specific :)