# Nested generics in typings function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, .d.ts

This question is about `.d.ts` as declarations for `.js` files.

I'm trying to declare a function that has a generic inside a generic but I can't seem to get it right. The function is essentially an `Array#forEach` function for objects (`{[key: string]: E}`).

I tried the following, but VSCode intellisense doesn't seem to comprehend the types of the property values of the object.

Typings File:

```
export module Util {
    export function forEach<K, T extends { [key: string]: K }>(obj: T, callbackfn: (value: K, key: string, object: T) => void): void;
}
```

JavaScript Call:

```
if (undefined) var { Util } = require("./globals");
/** @type {{ [key:string]: number }} */
var obj = {};
Util.forEach(obj, function (value, key, object) { });
```

Source code of `forEach`:

```
function forEach(obj, callbackfn) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Object)) throw Error("Util.forEach called on non object");
    for (var key in obj) callbackfn.call(obj, obj[key], key, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problems with your code. As you can see, the object properties types show correctly, when imported in a JS file and TS file as well:

[image]

Tested with Visual Studio Code 1.43.1 and Node.js 13.11.0

I have uploaded the code here: https://github.com/Guerric-P/typescript-test

**Edit:**

Now I understand your actual question, here is how you do it:

```
export module Util {
    export function forEach<T, T1 extends keyof T, T2 extends T[keyof T]>(obj: T, callbackfn: (value: T2, key: T1, object: T) => void): void;
}
```

Which gives the following:

[image]
[image]

If you want more details on why the key type is `string | number` instead of `string`, please check this question: [Keyof inferring string | number when key is only a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808160/keyof-inferring-string-number-when-key-is-only-a-string)

Comment: In my example i declare the object as `{ [key:string]: number }`, so all of the values are numbers

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is this:

```
export function forEach<T extends object>(obj: T, callbackfn: (value: T[keyof T], key: keyof T, object: T) => void): void {
  if (!(obj instanceof Object)) throw Error("Util.forEach called on non object");
  for (var key in obj) callbackfn.call(obj, obj[key], key, obj);
}

const a = {
  test: 1,
  test2: 2,
  test3: 'me'
};

forEach(a, (value, key, obj) => {})
```

You need only 1 generic parameter! You can infer the rest of types from it
[image]

This works even with stricter types:

[image]

**Update**: add `d.ts` file:

```
export module Util {
  export function forEach<T extends object>(obj: T, callbackfn: (value: T[keyof T], key: keyof T, object: T) => void): void
}
```

Comment: Your answer uses Typescript. I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: what you need to do is to extract typescript to d.ts :) it's easy. I can do this for you

Comment: Changed `export function forEach<T, K extends T[keyof T]>(obj: T, callbackfn: (value: K, key: string, object: T) => void): void;` to `export function forEach<T extends Object>(obj: T, callbackfn: (value: T[keyof T], key: string, object: T) => void): void;` (Don't see the point of using `key: keyof T` if it's always going to be a `string`).

Comment: it's not always a string! look at typescript literal types! https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types

Comment: I'm using `for (var key in obj)` the value of `key` will always be a `string`.

Comment: @nickzoum not always, especially in typescript ;) it can be a stricter type. As I said look at literal types.

Comment: I'm using `for (var key in obj)` in `JavaScript` therefore it will always be a `string`. I'm not using any typescript just `.d.ts` for better documentation.