# Keyof gives unexpected result

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When typing this in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

I expect `Key` to be `string` but it is `string | number`. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyof inferring string | number when key is only a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808160/keyof-inferring-string-number-when-key-is-only-a-string)

Comment: Workaround is -  `Record<string, number>`, and the behavior you have is by design