# TypeScript - property of string-keyed interface does not pass as a string type

Tags: typescript

I have run into a problem with an interface with keys defined as strings. Its property cannot be passed to a function that accepts strings types. I have reduced it to the simplest case.

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsgNoDWEAngFzI5hSgDmAunXCFYQL6GEwAriARhgGEPQhh02AJLhoIOABsAFFkxZkdBkxDMANMgBuqwSg5cAlDtMZgAEwJ8Bw0eMk5psrAB4AFWQIAA9IEEc8SioMGDQtHAA+DS06AOMzFQs6XxxSANZbOhMHZyISAHoK5AB1AAsqZEcMCDwwOuA2uswAd2ROYKhMKGRgOOjRvEcIGFAIZzg8OHpGFgB+ZDUVOeQAJmtiZCrkAFEhjBG4MGRNbBpD45IAQShmQQBbCHBkWOQwKiwKAA5AEgZNkCAMNdFjhgMxlAAjFQoMAYG5wKBwT6QEa-f6A5BAvQsIEAOge1RIAQBwOJBmQAB8IR8EdAwZ0IVD+jhYfC4EiUWj8bTVgYycgKSRkNSCUCQCy2eDIdCeXDEci-kKaYS6cwyYdvDItAoccp1LcsBlzBBrABuXiEIA))

```
interface Props {
  [key: string]: any
}

function setPropInternal(prop : string, value : any) : void {}

function setProp<T extends keyof Props>(prop: T, value: Props[T]) : void {
  // Why does this throw an error if key is defined as a string? (line 2)
  // Error at prop:
  //  Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  //   Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
  //    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  setPropInternal(prop, value);
}
```

Comment: interesting, `keyof Props` is `string | number` [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsgNoDWEAngFzI5hSgDmAunXCFYQL6FhUsKAILIAvMkpUMMNJlwBuIA)

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808262/6513723 or short explanation: indexing with numbers is internally converted to string in JavaScript, so using `keyof` on an object with a string index signature will always return `string | number`.

Comment: Thanks. For quick reference, this can be fixed with: ... updateProp<T extends(keyof Props & string)>(prop : T, value : Props[T]) { ...