# Can't make TypeScript understand that the type of an object's keys can only be a string

Tags: typescript

In the example below, is there any way to make Typescript understand that `val` can only be a `string` ?

```
type Obj = {[key: string]: string}

const test = (obj: Obj) => {
  let val: keyof typeof obj;
  // Why type of `val` is string | number ??
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808160/keyof-inferring-string-number-when-key-is-only-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may extract only types you need:

```ts
    ...
    let val: Extract<keyof typeof obj, string>;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will close my question since it's a duplicate.