# TypeScript mapped types question. Why can't get the keys of interfaces union?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface Data {
  A: {
    a1: string;
    a2: string;
  };
  B: {
    b1: number;
    b2: string;
  };
}


type TransformDataKey<V extends string, T extends string> = `--${V}-${T}`;
type TransformData<
  V extends string,
  K extends keyof Data,
  D = Data[K]
> = {
  [k in TransformDataKey<V, keyof D>]: string | number; // <-- error on "keyof D"
};

type K = TransformData<'abc', 'A'>; // <-- this is correct
```

When trying to access `keyof D` in the marked line, I get the following error:

> Type 'keyof D' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
> Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2344)

Which I understand is because `keyof D` resolves to `never` due to `A` and `B` not having fields in common. But how can it resolve to `string | number | symbol` if none of the keys are neither `number` nor `symbol`?

However the `type K` resolves correctly to

```
type K = {
  --abc-a1: string | number;
  --abc-a2: string | number;
}
```

Is there any way of doing this kind of mapping correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808262/11758901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because as of Typescript 2.9, [the keyof operator also supports number and symbol named properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html).

Quoting from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808262/11758901):

> This is because JavaScript converts numbers to strings when indexing an object

So as per the recommendation from the answer above, I'd say this should do the trick:

```
interface Data {
  A: {
    a1: string;
    a2: string;
  };
  B: {
    b1: number;
    b2: string;
  };
}


type TransformDataKey<V extends string, T extends string> = `--${V}-${T}`;
type TransformData<
  V extends string,
  K extends keyof Data,
  D = Data[K]
> = {
  [k in TransformDataKey<V, Extract<keyof D, string>>]: string | number; //no error
};

type K = TransformData<'abc', 'A'>; // <-- this is correct
```

or better yet (since keys of type number would be ignored otherwise):

```
interface Data {
  A: {
    "a1": string;
    2: string;
  };
  B: {
    b1: number;
    b2: string;
  };
}


type TransformDataKey<V extends string, T extends string | number> = `--${V}-${T}`;
type TransformData<
  V extends string,
  K extends keyof Data,
  D = Data[K]
> = {
  [k in TransformDataKey<V, Extract<keyof D, string | number>>]: string | number;
};

type K = TransformData<'abc', 'A'>;
```

I don't know how to deal with symbols here however. Seems like string interpolation with symbols is not allowed in JavaScript so wthat's probably why.

```
const fooSymbol = Symbol('foo');
const test = `--${fooSymbol}`; // Implicit conversion of a 'symbol' to a 'string' will fail at runtime. Consider wrapping this expression in 'String(...)'.
```

When running this, we get a runtime error:

> Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string