# Typescript typing with keyof always has ambigious typing, even when specified

Tags: typescript, socket.io, typescript-generics

```js
type StringTyped = {[key: string]: any};

type ShouldBeStringType = keyof StringTyped;
const test:ShouldBeStringType = 2; // but this is allowed?
```

I am trying to have a generic Type that relies on `keyof` actually returning the type which is specified, but `keyof` seems to always return the type `string | number`, even if I specify beforehand, that the keys of the object are strings.

```js
type StringTyped = {[key: string]: any};

class Emitter<T extends StringTyped> {
    emit<K extends keyof T>(socket: Socket, event: K, data: T[K]): void {
        socket.emit(event, data);
    }
    broadcast<K extends keyof T>(io: Server, room: string, event: K, data: T[K]): void {
        io.to(room).emit(event, data);
    }
    broadcastAll<K extends keyof T>(io: Server, event: K, data: T[K]): void {
        io.emit(event, data);
    }
}
```

I am trying to streamline socket-io with a wrapper and the reason I need the return type of `keyof` to be a `string` is that `event` has to be a `string`. The question is how to make this work or if there is a better way to type `key` and `value` pairs as paramater.

I tried to just use `event.toString()` when `event` is needed, but the `.toString()` could be overwritten to then execute some arbitrary code and could maybe lead to a security issue. (not if this concern is really valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce the type `ShouldBeStringType` as a string, you can use the following:

```js
type ShouldBeStringType = keyof StringTyped & string;
```

This answer is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54784203/6456163), originally by [madox2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741871/madox2).