# Why does `keyof Record<string, any>` return `string`, but `keyof { [K: string]: any }` return `string | number`?

Tags: typescript

Trying to understand the differences between `Record` and `object`. [I know that `keyof object` should return `string | number` (or optionally, `symbol`).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808262/2535504)

[TypeScript docs on `Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) don't provide much helpful context. I thought `Record` was a handy shortcut for `{ [K: key]: value }`, and would expect them to behave similarly. However:

```
type ObjectType = { [K: string]: any }
type ObjectTypeKeys = keyof ObjectType // string | number

type RecordType = Record<string, any>
type RecordTypeKeys = keyof RecordType // string
```

---

*A bit more noodling...*

`Record` is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * Construct a type with a set of properties K of type T
 */
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
```

Interestingly:

```
type Test = keyof { [K in 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz']: any } // 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
```

So the answer seems to lie somewhere within the behavior of `Record`'s usage of `in K`, since the above type doesn't intersect with `number`.

Put another way, why is this legal?

```
const Foo: Record<string, any> = { 0: 'test' }
type FooKeys = keyof Foo // string
const Bar = Foo[0] // Works
```

Is this a TypeScript-ism that I need to put up with or is there some logical explanation that I'm overlooking?

Comment: All object keys are either strings or symbols in JavaScript. There is no number keys - `{ 0: "hello" }` is a valid JS object where the key would be the string `"0"`. TS does try to also differentiate numbers in order to accurately type check indexed types like arrays. But it's an artificial divide and doesn't make sense to enforce fully in both ways - adding a the "number" key to an object that has strings for keys is fine, But adding a string key to an array is an error. For why `keyof ObjectType` report numbers and strings, I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @VLAZ Indeed. The final example of `{ 0: 'test' }` would be more appropriately written as `{ '0': 'test' }`, but was included to illustrate an inconsistency in how TypeScript sees that specific `Record` with `string` keys, but doesn't throw a type error when accessing that same `Record` with a numeric index. (You might also expect it to error on the `0` definition in the first place.)

Comment: @sheng - Re expecting it to fail on `{ 0: 'test' }`, that's defined in JavaScript: Numeric literals are valid property name literals in object initializer expressions ("object literals"). The resulting property's key is a string in the normal form for the number. Just another arcane thing about JavaScript syntax. :-) Interesting question though about why `number` is a valid key type for `{ [Key: string]: any }`. I get why it isn't for `Record<string, any>`, but not why it is for the other.

Comment: "*{ 0: 'test' } would be more appropriately written as { '0': 'test' }*" no, they are the same. Exactly how `{ foo: "test" }` and `{ "foo": "test" }` are the same. You can use a literal token but it's converted to a string in either case. Using a dynamically evaluated key like `{ [key]: "test }` would still turn the value to a string, e.g., for `key = ["hello", "world"]` the object in the end would be `{ "hello,world": "test" }`. All non-symbol keys are strings. That's why it's hard to *forbid* adding strings-that-contain-a-number to an object. It's easier to only allow numbers.

Comment: And, again, the whole distinction in TS is to allow typing of indexed objects. Disallowing strings to arrays is OK and expected. Disallowing numbers to string-typed keys is...not especially useful since it's exceptionally rare it'd be an issue. TS tries to make best effort to be useful. However, it can't even watch for non-negative integers as keys. It happily allows you to access `arr[3.14]` which isn't a valid index. It tries its best but it's still limited.

Comment: I see what you're saying, thank you both for clarifying.

Comment: See the linked q/a for more info.

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz! "[I]t's possible to confirm that it is this way. As for why it's this way, that's harder to say for certain." — I was afraid of that. Greetings from the other side of our fine state!